# Problema na consulta com Between no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Em um sistema de controle de entrada e saída existe uma tabela `cad_entrada_saida` onde possui duas colunas no banco `dEntrada` e `dSaida`, estas duas colunas estão como `varchar` e gravando os dados no formato `dd/mm/yyyy H:i` *definido pelo antigo Desenvolvedor*.

Ao realizar o `SELECT` nessa tabela usando `BETWEEN` é retornado datas fora do intervalo definido.

```
SELECT * FROM cad_entrada_saida 
    WHERE dEntrada BETWEEN '01/01/2017 06:00' AND '01/01/2017 23:00'
```

Já tentei usando a Função `str_to_date`

```
SELECT * FROM cad_entrada_saida WHERE dEntrada 
   BETWEEN str_to_date('01/01/2017 06:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AND
           str_to_date('01/01/2017 23:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
```

Ambas consultas me retornam datas fora deste intervalo.

Comment: Lucas algum resposta te serviu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se `dEntrada` e `dSaida` estão com o tipo de dado `varchar`, eles precisam sem convertidos para ***data*** na `SQL` também, ou seja, esses campos também devem utilizar `str_to_date`, observe:

```
SELECT * FROM cad_entrada_saida 
WHERE str_to_date(dEntrada, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') BETWEEN 
      str_to_date('01/01/2017 06:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AND
      str_to_date('01/01/2017 23:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
```

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [13.7 Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [12.3.7 Conversion Between Date and Time Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html)

Comment: Exemplo que estava fazendo no SQL Fiddle para a resposta: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05649a/8/0

Comment: Era o que eu precisava Virgilio. Funcionou! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

As colunas devem ser do tipo `datetime`.

Caso queira manter o tipo corrente (`varchar`), terá que fazer um cast.

Sugiro usar em conjunto com a função `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Abaixo, apenas o trecho que interessa, a condicional `WHERE`

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(dEntrada,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01 06:00:00') 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01 06:23:00')
```

A entrada deve estar no formato ISO 8601 (yyyy-mm-dd). Esqueci de trocar quando editei a resposta.

Quanto a desempenho, não é a questão aqui. Aliás, se formos tratar isso tudo como uma questão de desempenho, a resposta correta é a do @UpTI pois resolve os dois problemas num só.

O motivo de ter postado com `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` é para evitar postar o mesmo que outros já postaram, então fica como um meio alternativo e outro motivo é, apesar da resposta do @UpTI ser a mais adequada, dependendo do caso pode ser um pesadelo. Por exemplo, se o sistema em geral necessita que a coluna `dEntrada` seja mesmo um varchar, uma mudança para o tipo `datetime` poderia gerar diversos bugs no sistema como um todo. Uma dor de cabeça enorme, custo de tempo para adaptar, etc. Por vezes um cast pode ser melhor como uma gambiarra temporária.

Claro, com o tempo deve consertar e desenhar a estrutura de forma apropriada e consistente.

Comment: Pois é @DanielOmine, levei a proposta para a podermos modificar estas colunas, tendo em vista a melhor manutenção do sistema e uma melhora na precisão dos relatórios. Referente a sua resposta o valor passado dentro do `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` depois do `BETWEEN` não esta nesse formato, teria que converter primeiro certo?

Comment: Sim, teria que converter para o padrão ISO 8601. Dependendo de como se dá o input, de qual linguagem usa, é fácil converter.

Answer (score 0):

Colunas do tipo `varchar` não podem ser consultadas com um *intervalo*.

Você deve converter sua tabela para o tipo `datetime` para então consultar os registros definindo um intervalo. Tente usar o mesmo padrão do **MySQL**: `('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: Levei a proposta para o gestor! Sempre trabalhei data em `SQL` como `datetime`! Obrigado.