# Tempo médio em segundos

Tags: mysql, data, bigint

Olá, no meu select preciso achar o tempo médio de atendimento (TMA) entre duas colunas formato BIGINT sendo elas:

> Data: DtBegin (inicio) e DtEnd (fim)

São do formato "dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss", quero saber em segundos quanto tempo durou cada atendimento, não posso mexer em nada do banco quero apenas na visualização.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Create Table

```
Create Table Interaction 
    IDInteraction   bigint(20),
  DtBegin   datetime,
    DtEnd   datetime,
  IDuser    int(11),
  IDSupervisor  int(11),
  OperatorName  varchar(200),
  SupervisorName    varchar(200),
  IDSession bigint(20),
  IDMailingItem bigint(20),
  IDContact bigint(20),
  Notes longtext,
  IDResult  int(11),
  ResultDescription varchar(100),
  IDCampaign    int(11),
  CampaignDescription   varchar(200),
    IsAutomatic bit(1),
    IDChannel   int(11),    
    IsCallback  bit(1)`
```

---

> Insert

```
INSERT INTO Interaction (417, 
'16/05/2016 20:00:40', 
'16/05/2016 20:01:18', 
1, 
2, 
'Fulano BR',
'SUPERVISOR 001',
 null,
 null,
4, 
 null,
2, 
'AfterCallEnd',
1, 
'Campanha SMS', 
1, 
9,
null);
```

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo de como é essa tabela com dados e como seria um resultado por exemplo?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic adicionei uma imagem do meu select o resultado seria a diferença de segundos entre o inicio e o fim, gira em torno de 1,04, 0,03 e assim vai

Comment: Colunas BIGINT no formato "dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss"? As colunas não são DATETIME ou VARCHAR?

Comment: Kaleb fiz uma edição, dá uma olhada na resposta e se é isso... !!! a média em segundos?

Comment: @abfurlan são bigint mesmo :/

Comment: Kaled eu te fiz uma pergunta qual seria o resultado de uma linha? e outra pelo TIME_TO_SEC não vai rolar assim!

Comment: Os campos não eram BIGINT? Pelo código de criação de sua tabela são datetime! :/

Comment: Conseguiu resolver, eu também fiz uma edição dá uma olhada!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu tentei seu código sem o "from_unixtime" e funcionou embora eu ja tivesse tentado anteriormente kk muito obrigado kk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Seria uma conversão para DateTime](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202020/54880) com [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), depois com [unix_timestamp()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) para um valor em inteiros e uma divisão por 2 que seria a média do resultado:

```
SELECT dtEnd, dtEnd, 
       ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dtEnd) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dtBegin)) / 2) media
from tempo tempo
```

A média nesse caso tem sua saída em segundos tipo **30** segundos, **19** segundos e assim por diante.

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [13.7 Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [12.3.7 Conversion Between Date and Time Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html)
- [UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php)
- [UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Comment: Não funcionou, acredito que seja pelo TIMESTAMP, pois os campos são bigint, consegui algo mais ou menos com TIME_TO_SEC, ele retorna o total de duração em segundos, mas em alguns casos ele buga e mostra Null

Comment: Sabe o que você não foi claro por exemplo: qual é o resultado esperado por exemplo: `'16/05/2016 20:00:40', '16/05/2016 20:01:18'` qual é o resultado esperado? @KalebGabriel ???

Comment: Por exemplo **18/05/2016 10:58:34,18/05/2016 11:16:40 = 3486**

Comment: Só para saber aonde você tirou esse valor `3486` como chegou nesse valor @KalebGabriel?

Comment: Olha minha pergunta la em cima eu mudei a imagem, penúltima linha de um codigo que fiz de TESTE usando o TIME_TO_SEC

Comment: @KalebGabriel ta errado esse valor!!! veja de 10:58 até 11:16 tem 18 minutos (vamos fazer dos valores em minutos que também entra no cenário) então multiplicando por 60 seria 1080 a diferença de uma para a outra e a média 540 segundos. Ou Não?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo 1080, esta errado kkk, como pode ver alguns estão certos, outros nulos e alguns errados :/, dificil trabalhar com Bigint

Comment: Amigo não estou entendendo o BIGINT, pouco importa isso. Vou editar a minha fazendo isso que eu te disse ai se testa! Cara pode testar ta certo a maneira proposta nessa resposta

Comment: É mas nada do que estão me sugerindo esta retornando valor apenas o TIME_TO_SEC deu resultado mesmo que errado :/

Comment: Não estou lhe entendendo, cara eu fiz a conta eu dei o código que faz isso e você diz que não está certo, como assim? o código que eu te passei não funcionou?

Comment: Não disse que esta errado, mas não funcionou, retorna apenas campos nulos, tudo vazio.

Comment: passa a SQL aqui para mim ver o que você está fazendo? com o meu exemplo?

Comment: segue : 
`SELECT
  DtBegin,
  DtEnd,
  IDInteraction,
  DATE_FORMAT(DtBegin, '%m-%Y') AS Mes_Ano,
  TIME_TO_SEC(DtEnd-DtBegin) as TESTE,
  ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(dtEnd,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')) - 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(dtBegin,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'))) / 2) media
FROM Interaction
LIMIT 100;`

Comment: Eu precisa de uma cópia da sua tabela! porque o comando está correto! Tem como mandar o layout da tabela? e alguns dados !

Comment: irei postar na pergunta

Comment: @KalebGabriel se sua data já é um datetime não precisa utilizar str_to_date, verifique agora com essa edição.

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `FROM_UNIXTIME` para converter para data e para obter a diferença a função `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.

```
SELECT 
DtBegin,
DtEnd,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,FROM_UNIXTIME(DtBegin),FROM_UNIXTIME(DtEnd)) AS TempoSegundos
from Interaction
```

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da653/9)**

Comment: São BIGINT mesmo, se nao eu teria usado o TIMESTAMPDIFF, e o DATE_format esta certo, estava testando o %s para segundos quando tirei o print, eu uso "%m-%y"

Comment: @KalebGabriel seria isso? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da653/2

Comment: Funciona mas não no meu caso, só retorna valores nulos, acho que é pelo formato do campo TIMESTAMP nao funciona com BIGINT e não posso converter, é database de cliente.

Comment: desculpe agora que vi que vc criou os campos como Bigint, mas rodei e retorna apenas valores nulos

Comment: @KalebGabriel estranho, pq no Fiddle funcionou convertendo o BIGINT

Comment: Será que não é o formato dos dados que vc inseriu? nao sei como inserir data com hora, mas se fosse só a data faria ('dd/mm/aaaa', 'dd/mm/aaaa', 1234)

Comment: Veja aqui o exemplo com os mesmos dados que retornaram `NULL` segundo sua imagem. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95583/1.

Comment: Certo mas só funcionou pq vc usou **unix_timestamp(str_to_date** no insert não é

Comment: @KalebGabriel Sim mais pra gravar em BIGINT é necessário converter a data para timestamp, caso contrário não seria possível gravar uma data num campo bigint

Answer (score 0):

Amigo!  Você não está conseguindo usar `TIMESTAM` por que seu tipo de dados é `DATETIME`. Ou seja, sua query está buscando um tipo de dados sendo que no banco é outro.